# Processing commands with inaccurate natural language strings

Tags: c#, .net, nlp

We're designing a system which can accepts commands in this format

```
command context
```

The context is defined from a list of about 200 tuples of words such as:

```
physical therapy
cardiac
physician visit
hospital inpatient
hospital outpatient
etc.
```

We want the system to be able to correct user errors such as spelling mistakes but also to understand that "physical therapy" is the same as "physical therapist" AND also to accept synonyms

Finally, if it's not an exact match, it should ask the user to disambiguate between the best matches

This is how I'm thinking of doing it:

1. Stem both the context words and incoming queries
2. Delete/isolate command strings from the query
3. Check for and correct any anagrams (however: this only covers one category of spelling mistakes)
4. Look for an exact word match
5. Look for "close matches"

This doesn't feel like a neat solution, especially steps 3 and 5.

What's a better/easier way to do this? Any libraries to do it in C#, bonus.

Can Lucene do this perhaps? Any guidance appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It may be too imprecise for your purposes, but [Soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) is a common algorithm for telling if two words "sound similar".

Answer (score 0):

I think Lucene would be best applied only at steps 4 and 5, as Lucene currently only supports approximate matching in the "glob" sense (wildcard characters -- "?" for matching a single character and "*" for matching multiple characters).

There is a whole set of literature on approximate matching -- I would start with the [agrep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agrep) work and proceed from there (but in part that is because I'm familiar with agrep).